# Log analytics in Databricks Azure

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have created a log analytics workspace which used the grab all metrics from a databricks cluster.

Actually, my query would be to get the times when the cluster were running more than 10 worker instances. Can I find this information through log analytics in azure for databricks?

any hint would be apprecited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Log4j appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) to send your Azure Databricks application logs to Azure Log Analytics.

Refer [Send application logs using Log4j](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/application-logs#send-application-logs-using-log4j) to know the steps to implement the same.

You can also visualize the Databricks resource metrics using `Grafana` and Virtual Machine. Check this official Microsoft documentation for the same. [Use dashboards to visualize Azure Databricks metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/dashboards#visualizations-in-the-dashboards)