# Azure Databricks and log analytics setup requires a restart or rebuild?

Tags: azure, logging, databricks, analytics

Followed this link to setup Databricks and Log Analytics:

[Log analytics in Databricks Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72609690/log-analytics-in-databricks-azure)

My question is, does this require a cluster/workspace rebuild or restart?

Ideally a restart is preferable since we have jobs running using the Databricks URL.

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, does this require a cluster/workspace rebuild or restart?

There is no need to rebuild the cluster, **restart action is sufficient** for Azure Databricks and log analytics setup.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/azure-diagnostic-logs#events), you can use this diagnostic log event schema `Microsoft.Databricks/<category>/<actionName>` such as `Microsoft.Databricks/<clusters>/<restart>`

You can refer to [Monitoring Azure Databricks with Log Analytics](https://dustinvannoy.com/2021/08/09/monitoring-azure-databricks-with-log-analytics/) and [Azure Databricks Best Practices](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDatabricksBestPractices/blob/master/toc.md)

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look at those documents.